# JSDom not loading relative scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mocha.js, jsdom

So I'm trying to set up a mocha test with jsdom and after many attempts at debugging I narrowed down the problem to jsdom executing absolute URL scripts (e.g. `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js`) but not relative URL scripts (e.g. `js/script.js`).

My test.js is below:

```
var assert = require("assert");
var fs = require('fs');
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

describe('Foo Test', function(){
    it('Foo Check', function(done){
        this.timeout(5000);

        jsdom.env({
            html: fs.readFileSync('index.htm')
            ,features: {
                FetchExternalResources: ["script"]
                ,ProcessExternalResources: ["script"]
            }
            ,done: function(errors, window){
                if(errors != null) console.log('Errors', errors);
                var $ = window.$; // $ is defined
                var foo = window.foo; //foo is undefined
                assert(foo);
                done();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the error:
`Uncaught AssertionError: undefined == true`

The htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Foo</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>      
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var foo = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to `jsdom.env`, remove `html` and use `file`. I've tested this modification of your code with jsdom 3.1.2, and it works:

```
    jsdom.env({
        file: path.join(__dirname, "index.htm")
        ,features: {
        [... etc ...]
```

(You also need to add `var path = require("path")` with your other `require` calls.)

The problem with using `html` is that then jsdom has no idea what the base URL of the HTML is. If you use `file`, it will load the code from the path you give and use the path as the base URL.

Comment: Got a chance to try it out and it worked without the path.join since the test.js is in its own folder (so it was trying to find a index.htm in the test folder as oppose to the root).

Answer (score 1):

As of 3.0 the url parameter is now set to about:blank by default instead of implcitly set to current dir. Once I added `url: __dirname` the test came up green isntantly.

```
var assert = require("assert");
var fs = require('fs');
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

describe('Foo Test', function(){
    it('Foo Check', function(done){
        this.timeout(5000);

        jsdom.env({
            html: fs.readFileSync('index.htm')
            ,url: __dirname
            ,features: {
                FetchExternalResources: ["script"]
                ,ProcessExternalResources: ["script"]
            }
            ,done: function(errors, window){
                if(errors != null) console.log('Errors', errors);
                var $ = window.$; // $ is defined
                var foo = window.foo; //foo is undefined
                assert(foo);
                done();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also I want to mention that jQuery 2.x does not seem compatible currently with jsdom.

Comment: Also note that as of v10 jsdom has a new api, but it still supports the old one, so in order to use the old syntax you'll need to include it like this:
`var jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");` (see [explanation in Github](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/lib/old-api.md))